# How to render Html with smarty

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to render my raw HTML with smarty.

```
{if !empty($brand.description)}
  {$brand.description}
{/if}
```

The original text contains spaces and text returns, but when displayed, HTML is shown as plain text.

Also, I tried to add `{$brand.description|strip_tags:'UTF-8'}` as a filter for my string. But it's only deleting my HTML.

How can my smarty template render this string as pure HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is...

```
{$brand.description nofilter}
```

Also, you can disable this indicator by change default smarty behavior:

```
$smarty->setEscapeHtml(false);
```